# How to display the surface as triangulation line in VTK?

Tags: visualization, vtk, surface, triangulation

I use the marching cubes to obtain the surface of a volume, which is actually vtkPolyData. Then, I want to visualize the vtkPolyData as triangulation lines (the first picture) rather than the surface rendering (the second picture).

My current code is：

```
surface = vtk.vtkMarchingCubes()
surface.SetInputData(vtkImage)
surface.ComputeNormalsOn()
surface.SetValue(0, 0.5)
surface.Update()

mapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
mapper.SetInputConnection(surface.GetOutputPort())
mapper.ScalarVisibilityOff()

renderer = vtk.vtkRenderer()
renderer.SetBackground(0.1, 0.2, 0.3)

renderWindow = vtk.vtkRenderWindow()
renderWindow.AddRenderer(renderer)

interactor = vtk.vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
interactor.SetRenderWindow(renderWindow)

actor = vtk.vtkActor()
actor.SetMapper(mapper)
actor.GetProperty().SetRepresentationToWireframe()
actor.GetProperty().ShadingOff()

renderer.AddActor(actor)
renderWindow.Render()
interactor.Start()
```

It can success visualize the second picture. How can I get the first picture using the "surface"?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SetRepresentationToWireframe()` method already controls whether to show the polydata as wireframe or surface... so the question is not very clear to me.

Comment: That's what I need. Thank you very much.